# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NotOlustur{1712dba} (eb74f985-d2c2-48d4-93de-d46a66d2e483) not attached to a context

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I'm trying to write a program that sets a file in the Drawable over the ImageView in another fragment when the Button in the BottomSheet is clicked. But i think my context is always null. Because when i tried to add nullability (for example : context?.resources), it doesn't work but the app doesn't crash either. Here is my fragments:

Main Fragment

```
package com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.R
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.databinding.FragmentNotOlusturBinding

class NotOlustur : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentNotOlusturBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNotOlusturBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.background.setOnClickListener {
            BottomSheet().show(parentFragmentManager, "newTaskTag")
        }
    }
    fun changeBackground0() {
        val background = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.background)
        val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(requireContext().resources, R.drawable.retrofuture, null)
        background?.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    }
}
```

Bottom Sheet Fragment

```
package com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.databinding.FragmentBottomSheetBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment

class BottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentBottomSheetBinding
    val NotOlustur = NotOlustur()

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        binding.imgPrew.setOnClickListener {
            NotOlustur.changeBackground0()
        }

        binding.imgPrew1.setOnClickListener {

        }

        binding.imgPrew2.setOnClickListener {

        }

        binding.imgPrew3.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Error Code

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NotOlustur{1712dba} (eb74f985-d2c2-48d4-93de-d46a66d2e483) not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:967)
    at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments.NotOlustur.changeBackground0(NotOlustur.kt:40)
    at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments.BottomSheet.onViewCreated$lambda-0(BottomSheet.kt:36)
    at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments.BottomSheet.$r8$lambda$mbZWmYt5DwS3MQ-Y8JU1Nc4q61M(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Fragments.BottomSheet$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7297)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7274)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:819)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28017)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Is this  how you  are calling  method in  you fragment on  button click binding.imgPrew.setOnClickListener {
            NotOlustur.changeBackground0()
        } ?

Comment: You can pass a variable of type `NotOlustur` to your bottom sheet. Currently you are creating a new instance of the fragment via `val NotOlustur = NotOlustur()` which is attached to any host context or activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a brand new instance of your `NotOlustur` fragment by doing this:

```
val NotOlustur = NotOlustur()
```

So, yes, that brand new instance of `NotOlustur` was never added to a FragmentManager, just as the error message says.

What you actually want is to get a reference to the fragment that created your `BottomSheet` Fragment. To do that, you need to make two changes:

1. Use the correct FragmentManager when adding your `BottomSheet`:

```
BottomSheet().show(childFragmentManager, "newTaskTag")
```

This is what properly ties your `NotOlustur` and `BottomSheet` fragments together, rather than being completely independent Fragments in the same FragmentManager. With this change, `BottomSheet` will be a child fragment of `NotOlustur`.

2. Retrieve the `NotOlustur` fragment by using `requireParentFragment()`

```
// Note, variables should generally have a lowercase letter
// so that they are not confused with a Class
val notOlustur get() = requireParentFragment() as NotOlustur
```

Instead of creating a brand new instance, we can use the correct nesting of the fragments to cast the result from `requireParentFragment` as your actual instance of `NotOlustur`. The `get()` here ensures that this line of code runs only when you actually access the variable, rather than instantly when the Fragment is created.

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized my mistake Have a good day and thnx again :)

Comment: If this helped answer your question, make sure to hit the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted to remove this question from the list still looking for answers. Best of luck going forward!